# How do I estimate the number of RSS subscribers?

Tags: website, rss, feed, atom-feed

I'm running a website, and would like to get a better idea how many subscribers I have. I can check the number of subscribers on Google Reader for my two feeds (RSS and Atom). I also have access to my server logs, so I sometimes collect all the IP addresses that access the feeds over a month or so and do a uniq.

Is that an accurate way of doing this? Are there other feed aggregators that I need to take into account? Any pitfalls when just going by IP address?

I've also thought about embedding an image in the feeds to get a better count. But do all feed readers load images automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch your feed to use [Google Feed Burner](http://feedburner.google.com) and these stats will be generated automatically for you.

Comment: That's not really an option, since I would need to switch over all my current subscribers.

Comment: @Robert - in a way, you would know which ones care enough to keep following.

Comment: Depending on how your feed is set you can replace your existing feed with a redirect to FeedBurner (this is easy in WordPress http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/redirecting-wordpress-feeds-to-feedburner.html)

Comment: Turns out there's a very clever module for Drupal (which I use) that redirects everybody except FeedBurner to FeedBurner. That seems to be the perfect solution. http://drupal.org/project/feedburner

Comment: @Goupi: good point, but I'd rather not risk losing lots of people ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, IP addresses have their ups and downs.  Most home clients (dial-up, broadband, etc) will have frequently changing IP addresses.  And those accessing from behind a corporate firewall will often all have the same IP or range of IP addresses, regardless of how many are actually connecting.  So going only by IP is not a really good indicator.  You can use it to make a guesstimate, but that's purely what it is.